# Having Two AC-DC converters in series

Tags: converter, series, ac-dc

I have two AC to DC full wave rectifier converters and want them to be in series to increase the voltage. The circuit is basically a generator going into a wave rectifier then a capacitor and resistor to smoothen out the ripples and so I also want a Voltage regulator in the circuit too to make sure that the output voltage is consistently 24 Volts. So would I have the two rectifier circuit in series before the voltage regulator and then have them go into the regulator together or would I need two regulators and then the two of them in series with each other to have a 24 Volt output.

Comment: In principle, it can. However, the circuit configuration need to be correct (floating, common 'ground'). Can you please post the circuit?

Comment: It would make your question clearer if you posted a schematic representing what you mean. The site has a schematic editor, just hit CTRL+M and you'll be there. Or something linked from the net would definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

If their AC inputs are galvanically isolated from each other, you can connect their outputs in series. Otherwise, you cannot.

[image]